# Web View in Java doesn't load Images when using loadContent

Tags: java, html, proxy, byte

**Background:** I'm getting introduced to clients and servers, and decided to make a simple proxy server.

**What the code does as of now:** The client side asks for a www.(enter site here).whatever (org, com, edu, etc.) then, the server takes that input in, and calls my WebsiteToHTML class, which converts that whole page to a byte array. The server then stores that byte array to it's own byte array variable. The server then sends the size of that array back to the client, and then sends the byte array itself back to the client. Then, the client makes a byte array of the size sent from the server, and then makes the byte array equal to the byte array that the server sent back. I then have an html string that is made from looping through the byte array and appending all of the chars to the String. I then use WebView to output that String using the loadContent function.

**My Problem:** My problem lies in outputting images. For instance, if I wanted to go to www.google.com, my code would run perfectly, and the WebView does indeed output the google page. However, the big "Google" logo simply just says "google" in text. My guess is that the WebView doesn't pull the images from the href in the html. Thus, I am here.

**My Code:**

ProxyClient:

```
package proxy;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class ProxyClient extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final String IP = "localhost";
        byte[] b;
        final int PORT = 4444;
        String input;
        Socket s = new Socket(IP,PORT);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        InputStream inFromServer = s.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
        String html = "";


        System.out.println("Enter URL: ");
        input = scan.next();

        out.writeUTF(input);

        System.out.println("output sent: " + input);

        byte[] htmlBytes = new byte[in.readInt()];

        in.read(htmlBytes);

        for(int i = 0; i < htmlBytes.length; i++) {
            char c = (char)(htmlBytes[i] >= 0 ? htmlBytes[i] : htmlBytes[i]+256);

            html += c;
        }

        System.out.println(html);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Proxy Client");

        WebView webView = new WebView();


        webView.getEngine().loadContent(html);

        VBox vBox = new VBox(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Proxy Server:

```
package proxy;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ProxyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final int PORT = 4444;
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection Established");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        WebsiteToHTML converter;
        String site;

        site = "https://"+in.readUTF();
        converter = new WebsiteToHTML(site);
        byte[] html = converter.write();

        System.out.println("Link Receieved received: " + site);

        System.out.println("Converted HTMLto byte array: " + Arrays.toString(html));

        while(true) {
            out.writeInt(html.length);
            out.write(html);
        }

    }

}
```

WebsiteToHTML:

```
package proxy;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class WebsiteToHTML {

    URL myurl;
    String html;
    HttpsURLConnection con;
    InputStream ins;
    InputStreamReader isr;
    BufferedReader in;
    String masterString = "";
    byte[] b;

    public WebsiteToHTML(String httpsURL) throws IOException {
        myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
        ins = con.getInputStream();
        isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
        in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    }

    public byte[] write() throws IOException {
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

            masterString += inputLine + "\n";
        }

        b = masterString.getBytes();
        b = masterString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        in.close(); 
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren’t checking the value returned by `in.read(htmlBytes);`.  See [the method’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29).

Comment: Could you explain more? The value returned by in.read(byte[] b) is the number of bytes read and the byte array is stored into b. Regardless, the whole byte array is transported to the client, and the html is properly stored into a string. Could you correct me if I'm wrong, or explain more? Thanks for your input!

Comment: Just because you pass an array of length 4096 (or whatever) doesn’t mean that `in.read` will read 4096 bytes.  The array may be only partially filled.

Comment: It is not partially filled. I have made sure of that. All of the bytes have been sent and read and stored accordingly for www.google.com. I'm 100% that is not the problem. Although, I am unsure of why the images aren't loading, despite all the html being there

Comment: Are the image URLs relative?  Obviously the image files won’t exist on the server machine.

Comment: No. What the html does, as far as I know, sets the image in an href which accesses a web location where that image is stored. for example, the google logo is stored here: https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png though, the loadContent function doesn't fetch this image, or display it for that matter.

Comment: I wrote a small test and I was not able to reproduce your problem, using Java 11 and JavaFX 11.  It also works in Java 8.  Can you edit your question and show the output from your `System.out.println(html);` statement?